# Websockets not connecting with postman using nestjs

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, nestjs, nestjs-socket.io

I am trying to make a connection with websockets. If I need to connect to the postman I need to include `app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app));` to make it work. But once I include this line it stop connecting with my react native code. When I remove this line it starts connecting with react native code and not with postman. How can I make it work with both react native client side and postman.

Below is my gateway code

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
  OnGatewayInit,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  WebSocketServer,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
  @WebSocketServer()
  server!: Server;

  private logger: Logger = new Logger('AppGateway');

  @SubscribeMessage('msgToServer')
  handleMessage(client: Socket, payload: string): void {
    this.server.emit('msgToClient', payload);
  }

  afterInit(server: Server) {
    this.logger.log('Init');
  }

  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    this.logger.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]) {
    this.logger.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
  }
}
```

main.ts

```
import { AppModule } from 'app.module';
import { WsAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-ws';

async function setupApplication(): Promise<INestApplication> {
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app));
  await app.listen(port);
  return app;
}
```

In the above main.ts file. If I remove app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app)); then I am able to connect with my react native client code but then not with postman.

react native code

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {Button, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import io  from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');


export default function App() {
  const receiveMessage = () => {
    socket.on('msgToClient', msg => {
      console.log('msg', msg);
    });
  };

  const sendMessage = () => {
    socket.emit('msgToServer','test message');
  };

  useEffect(() => {

    receiveMessage()

  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Button title="Message" onPress={sendMessage} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Postman now has support to [Socket.io servers](https://blog.postman.com/postman-now-supports-socket-io/) (it's in beta):

Step by step from the provided link:

> 1. In the left-hand sidebar, click `New`.
> 2. Select `WebSocket Request`.
> 3. Within the new tab’s header, click the drop-down that says `Raw`, and select `Socket.IO` instead.
> 4. Type the address of your Socket.IO server into the URL bar.
> 5. Click `Connect`.

As you do not provide a specific `namespace` on the `@WebSocketGateway()` decorator and assuming that you are using the default NestJS port `3000`, the step `4` address would be:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

Additionally, if you are running NestJS in WSL, you might want to see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75200872/11322356)

Answer (score 0):

Postman uses the `ws:` protocol, which is what the `WsAdapter` is for. By default Nest uses `socket.io` as the de facto WebSocket adapter which does not connect via `ws` diectly, but via the `socket.io` engine. Your react code is using `socket.io` so your server code should use `socket.io` too. This does mean that you won't be able to use postman to test your websockets though, unless you keep swapping back and forth.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Then the above implementation is fine and working as expected.