# Postman wont connect to Nestjs websocket

Tags: websocket, socket.io, postman, nestjs

I am trying to connect to my Nestjs websocket with postman for rapid testing during development but I am having a lot of trouble getting postman to actually connect.

This is my errror

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000

Here is my server code:

```
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayInit, SubscribeMessage, WebSocketGateway } from '@nestjs/websockets';

@WebSocketGateway({ namespace: "test", cors: true })
export class AppGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection {

  private logger: Logger

  constructor() {
    this.logger = new Logger('AppGateway')
  }

  afterInit(server: any) {
    this.logger.log("Gateway is running")
  }

  handleConnection(client: any, ...args: any[]) {
    this.logger.log("Client Connected")
  }

  @SubscribeMessage('message')
  handleMessage(client: any, payload: any): string {
    return 'Hello world!';
  }

  
}
```

This is extremely simplistic because I actually spun up a new nestjs server incase it was something to do with authentication

Here is a picture of my postman UI to show what I am doing there (I am using socket-io v4 on my server which is why I have that option selected on postman)
[image]

I have also tried the url ws://127.0.0.1:8000/test but this produces the same error (also have tried using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1)

I know my websocket server is functioning correctly (and on the correct port) because I spun up a quick react app using the socketio client library and it connected to the websocket fine.

Here is the code to my quick react app:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'

function App() {

  const socket = io("http://localhost:8000/test")
  console.log(socket)
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have been stuck on this for a day or two now so any help would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem when running NestJS in WSL and trying to connect via Postman.

As far as I understood, there is a bug report that, when using socket.io feature, [Postman attempts to convert `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/11204) which does not work because it's not the WSL IP.

So, in order to make it work you need:

1. Open a PowerShell to get WSL IP (it changes every time WSL reboots):

```
wsl hostname -I
```

2. Use the output IP to connect via Postman:

```
http://<ip>:8000/test
```

About `http` or `ws`, using socket.io, it doesn't matter if you choose `http` or `ws` to connect, [socket.io docs tells us the following](https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-initialization/#from-a-different-domain)

> You can use either https or wss (respectively, http or ws).